# TYPO3 Not able anymore to translate CE's to other languages

Tags: typo3, translation, typo3-7.6.x, tx-gridelements

Is there a way to 'reset' or db entries to delete or something else without deleting all content already translated... (and would that solve the issue?)

In the first go all translation went well, I chose a 'one tree' setup pressing translate rather then copy, but adding and modifying the content over time certain elements where not available for translation anymore ...

at one point the second step in translation asked for the origin language (if I recall well) and trying to resolve I chose another language than the default, now I do not have the choice anymore and the record summary proposes elements from german rather than from my default language (italian) which might be the problem since I can only introduce new content in the default language.

if I try to localize from the list view clicking the language flag, in the language selection field I get `[INVALID VALUE("1")]` and as only option `(Default) [0]` to select ...

I use **TYPO3 V7.6.13**, **EXT:gridelements** and **EXT:t3sbootstrap** (the nested CE's where the first to show trouble)

content of my database table sys_language: (my default lang is italian)

```
uid | pid | tstamp | hidden | title   | flag |
 1     0    ...        0      English    gb
 2     0    ...        0      German     de
```

does anyone know good reference or a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check (as suggested by bernd) if your language setup is valid:

- do you have a sys_language record for every added language in your
  root-page ? *(you can control the sys_language table with phpMyAdmin)*
- is the page translated ?

in my case that was all fine but I needed a **thorough cleanup**:

- I deleted all hidden records in the backend
- I activated the system extension '**recycler**' and deleted all in the
  list (from root-page recursive)
- I then checked with phpMyAdmin which records in tt_content where
  hidden (and did not show in the backend) and deleted those manually

once I did that the translate request answered perfectly and I could restore the missing CE's translations

note: I still had gridelements showing up in wrong sequence for the translation in the backend but correctly in the frontend, the nested CE's seem though, and of course '**CLEAR CASH FREQUENTLY**' to avoid surprises ...

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like your sys_language records (in yoour root-page, id = 0) are disabled or missing.
Those records make languages available for translation.

The other factor for translation selection is the translation of the current page. You need to have the page translated to a language (given above) to be able to translate any record in that page. That also is neccessary for pages which contain only data.

Comment: That is all fine in the setup, a doubt I have though, should also the default language be included in the root-page? I didn't think so ...

Comment: don't include a sys_language_record for your default language in the set of languages. (if you want to assign your default language a name and a flag you can do so in the page-TSConfig: `mod.SHARED.defaultLanguageFlag = de` `mod.SHARED.defaultLanguageLabel = deutsch`

Comment: thanks, have any other suggestions ? I checked what you said ... that's not it ...

Comment: have a look into your database: table sys_language. are there any records? are there records which are hidden? what uids are used? what value is the next used uid ('Next autoindex')?

Comment: udpdated my question to include the content of sys_language